# Alternative Cloud9 Collaborative Coding Environment (ASP .NET)

Tags: web-development, collaboration, cloud-service, asp.net

I'm looking for a collaborative coding environment much like Amazon's Cloud9 that supports ASP .NET applications. I didn't think it would be so difficult to find but I'm shocked at the lack of support. My brother and I design websites for friends/clients and often need to help one another when we are stuck. Currently we have to use a screen sharing app to accomplish this. Any platform or software that would allow us to edit the same project at the same time is what im looking for